# Undefined Property Error 1120 moving functions?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm very, VERY new at flash, and I've tried really hard to figure this out but it's not working. I keep getting the same error: "1120 Access of undefined property goGame" on line 96 and "1136 Incorrect number of arguments expected 1" on line 82.

I know both of these errors has something to do with the ordering of my functions, but I find that when I move the functions to be in front of the listener, more errors pop up demanding the same thing, and the only way I can fix those is moving them in front of each other etc. etc. So I'm kind of stuck. Help would be great appreciated!

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class StartGame extends MovieClip
    {
        var questions: Array=new Array();
        var correctAnswers: Array=new Array("blue","Russia","10","stone","true","hydrogen and oxygen","Rapunzel","magician","The Mona Lisa","string","12","mammal","lightning bolt","lacrosse","do");
        //Creates am array used for the Quiz Time function
        var i = 0;
        //used to track player's movements on board
        var lives = 3;
        //the # of lives given at the beginning of the game
        var collide: Boolean;
        var myTimer: Timer = new Timer(1000, 60);
        //used for timer in Storming the Castle Game
        var count = 0;
        //used to manage chibiKing movements







            //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrameLoop);
            //loops frames card so animation plays
            //function to get to the master instructions page

            //function to get the the main board



        function randomNumber(){
            var number=Math.round(Math.random()*5)+1; 
            return number;
        }//end randomNumber function    


        function StartGame() 
        {
            instructionsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, masterInstructions);
            //listener on instructions button to open the instructions page
            goButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playGame);
            //listener on the first play button to go to the game board


        }//end StartGame function
        function masterInstructions (event:MouseEvent) {
            gotoAndPlay(2);
            //takes you to the master instructions page
            goButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playGame);
            //listener on the first play button to go to the game board

        }// end masterInstructions function

        function rollDie (event:MouseEvent) {
            goRollButton.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, rollDie);
            //makes player unable to click roll button after pressing once
            goRollButton.visible = false;
            //removes visiblity of the roll button one clicked
            goButtonGame.visible = true;
            //makes game button appear so player can proceed to game
            var currentRoll=randomNumber();
            //randomly rolls a number between 1 and 6
            outputNumber.text=String(currentRoll);
            //displays the number rolled 
            var newMoves = i + currentRoll*10;
            //moves player forward, i being the number already moved
            //roll multipled by ten for frame movements of tween
            gameboy.gotoAndStop(newMoves);
            //player stops at the new position
            i = newMoves; 
            //i now changed to rolled number
            if (i<=300) {
                bossGame();
            }//if player gets to end of board, automatically start boss game

        }//end rollDie function

        function playGame (event: MouseEvent) {
            gotoAndPlay(3);
            //goes to main board game
            livesOutput.text=String(lives);
            //displays the 3 of lives the player has in the output box
            gameBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, girlJumps);
            //event listener for a pop up
            goRollButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rollDie);
            //when pressed, button calls die roll function
            goButtonGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goGame);
            //when pressed, chooses a random mini game 
            ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,ballStartDrag);
            ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ballEndDrag); 
            bear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, bearStartDrag);
            bear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, bearEndDrag);
            //functions to create drag and drops for objects on stage game board
            goButtonGame.visible=false;
            //does not display go button so player must roll dice before playing game

        }//end playGame function

        function ballStartDrag (evt:MouseEvent) {
            ball.startDrag();

        }//end ballStartDrag function

        function bearStartDrag (evt:MouseEvent) {
            bear.startDrag();
        }//end bearStartDrag function

        function ballEndDrag (evt:MouseEvent) {
            ball.stopDrag();
        }//end ballEndDrag function

        function bearEndDrag (evt:MouseEvent) {
            bear.stopDrag();
        }//end bearEndDrag function

        function girlJumps (evt:MouseEvent) {
            girlJump.gotoAndPlay(2);
            //has character on board to appear by playing tween
        }//end girlJumps function

        function bossGame (event:KeyboardEvent) {

            stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, finalBoss);
            //listener to player movement when keyboard is pressed

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movefireball);
            //listener to move the fireball

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);
            //listener to collisions between symbols on stage

            livesBoss.text=String(lives);
            //displays number of lives in text box

            fireball.height = 100;
            fireball.width = 100;
            fireball.x=40
            fireball.y=40
            fireball.xVelocity=8;
            fireball.yVelocity=8;
            //sets fireball parameters


        }//end bossGame function

        function movefireball (evt: Event) {
            fireball.x +=fireball.xVelocity;
            fireball.y +=fireball.yVelocity;
            //creates speeds of fireball
            checkfireballtoWall();
            //calls function

            var move1:Number=Math.ceil(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth) + 1;
            var move2:Number=Math.ceil(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth) + 1;
            //movements randomly created for king's movements

            if (count%100 == 0) {
                chibiKing.x= move1;
                chibiKing.y= move2;
                //reassigns chibiKing's movements
            }
            count++;
            //adds to count after so many seconds
        }//end movefireball function

        function checkfireballtoWall(){
            const TOP: Number= 50;
            const BOTTOM: Number= stage.stageHeight;
            const LEFT: Number= 50;
            const RIGHT: Number= stage.stageWidth - 50;
            const REVERSE: int = -1;
            //limits to fireball's movements

            if (fireball.y<TOP) {
                fireball.y=TOP;
                fireball.yVelocity*=REVERSE;
            }
            else if (fireball.y>BOTTOM) {
                fireball.y=BOTTOM;
                fireball.yVelocity*=REVERSE;
            }
            if (fireball.x<LEFT) {
                fireball.x=LEFT;
                fireball.xVelocity*=REVERSE;
            }
            else if (fireball.x>RIGHT) {
                fireball.x=RIGHT;
                fireball.xVelocity*=REVERSE;
            }
            //reassignes fireball's direction if fireball hits a certain area
        }//end checkfireballtoWall function

        function finalBoss (evt: KeyboardEvent) {
            if( evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT )  
                {player.x = player.x - 6;   
            }
            else if( evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP )  
                {player.y = player.y - 6;    
            }
            else if( evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )  
                {player.x = player.x + 6; 
            }
            else if( evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN )  
                {player.y = player.y + 6;
            }//allows player to move via keyboard control
        }//end finalBoss function

        function collision (evt: Event) {
            if (player.hitTestObject(chibiKing)) {
                gotoAndPlay(14);
                //if player hits the king, automatically go to win game screen
            if (player.hitTestObject(fireball)) {
                lives = lives - 1;
                //if player hits fireball, lose a life
                if (lives == 0) {
                    gotoAndPlay(11);}
                    //if lives equal to zero, go automatically to lose game screen
                livesBoss.text=String(lives);
                //display the lives remaining the text box
                }
        }//end collision function

        function dragonBattle (event:KeyboardEvent) {
                //inset Dragon Battle code
        }//end dragonBattle function







        function goGame (event:MouseEvent) {
            var gameChoose=randomNumber();
            //randomly chooses a game to play from the existing mini games
            if (gameChoose==1 || gameChoose == 2) {
                gotoAndPlay(4);
                //game 1 start screen
                goButton3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, stormingTheCastle);
                //listener to go to Storming the Castle Game
            }//end goGame function

            else if (gameChoose==3 && correctAnswers.length>0) {
                gotoAndPlay(7)
                //quiz time start screen
                quizTimeButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, quizTime);
                //quiz time start

            }
            else {gotoAndPlay(6);
                //game 2 start screen
                goButton5.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, dragonBattle);
                //listener to start game 2
                //wizardess.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, wizardessMagic);}

            }
        }//end goGame function

        function quizTime (event:MouseEvent) {

            questions [0]= "What colour is the sky?";
            questions [1]= "What is the world's biggest country in land mass?";
            questions [2]= "Do Re Mi Fa So La Ti...";
            questions [3]= "How many tentacles does a squid have?";
            questions [4]= "In Greek Mythology, looking into Medusa's eyes would turn you to...?";
            questions [5]= "True or False: Winnipeg has a hockey team.";
            questions [6]= "Water is made out of...?";
            questions [7]= "Which princess is the star of Disney's movie 'Tangled'?";
            questions [8]= "Harry Houdini was famous for being a(n)...?";
            questions [9]= "Leonardo Da Vinci famously painted what?";
            questions [10]= "What type of instrument is a sitar?";
            questions [11]= "How many are in a dozen?";
            questions [12]= "Humans are...?";
            questions [13]= "Harry Potter is famous for having a scar shaped as what on his forehead?";
            questions [14]= "What is the national sport of Canada?";
            //creates questions to go with answers created in startGame function    

            questionBox.text=questions[questions.length];
            //displays the question at the end of the array

            answerQuizTime.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quiz);
            //button to proceed to get quiz marker  


        }//end quizTime function

        function quiz (evt:MouseEvent){
            var userAnswer=String(answerInput.text);
            //saves the user's answer in userAnswer variable
            if (userAnswer==correctAnswers[questions.length]) {
                questions.pop();
                //removes question from end of array
                lives = lives + 1;
                //adds life to player's total lives
                gotoAndPlay(9);
                //goes to minigame win screen
            }
            else {
                questions.pop();
                //removes question from end of array
                lives = lives - 1;
                //removes life from player's total lives
                gotoAndPlay(10);
                //goes to minigame lose screen
            }
        }//end quiz function

        // handler function for the Arrow Keys to move Player across the stage
        function movePlayer(evt: KeyboardEvent) {

            // if key is right arrow, move Player to the right
            if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
                Player.x += 20;

            // if key is left arrow, move Player to the left
            } else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
                Player.x -= 20;
            }
        }//end movePlayer function



        function stormingTheCastle (event:MouseEvent) {
            // add a listener for a Frame Event
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameLoop);

            // add the listener for Keyboard events to the stage
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movePlayer);

            // create a custom speed property for each knight
            //start timer
            knight1.velocity = 4;
            knight2.velocity = 6;
            knight3.velocity = 3;
            knight4.velocity = 5;
            collide = false;
            myTimer.start();
        }//end stormingTheCastle function


        // each time frame 1 plays, move each knight
        //continues if no collision and count less than 60
        //return each night to top if it reaches the bottom
        function onFrameLoop(evt: Event) {
            if (collide == false && myTimer.currentCount < 60) {
                if (knight1.y > 292.2)
                    {knight1.y = 42.45;}
                if (knight2.y > 292.2)
                    {knight2.y = 42.45;}
                if (knight3.y > 292.2)
                    {knight3.y = 42.45;}
                if (knight4.y > 292.2)
                    {knight4.y = 42.45;}

                //move knights down by its speed property amount
                knight1.y = knight1.y + knight1.velocity;
                knight2.y = knight2.y + knight2.velocity;
                knight3.y = knight3.y + knight3.velocity;
                knight4.y = knight4.y + knight4.velocity;

                //trace timer count
                trace(myTimer.currentCount);

                //if Player is hit by a knight collision is true
                if (knight1.hitTestObject(Player) == true) {
                    collide = true;
                    trace("test");
                }
                if (knight2.hitTestObject(Player) == true) {
                    collide = true;
                }
                if (knight3.hitTestObject(Player) == true) {
                    collide = true;
                }
                if (knight4.hitTestObject(Player) == true) {
                    collide = true;
                }
                else {
                if (lives == 0) {
                    gotoAndPlay(11);}
                //trace Game Over when collision is true
                trace("GAME OVER");

                gotoAndPlay(10);

                }

        } //end onFrameLoop function


    }

                }//end startGame function

    }//end class function

}//end package
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

In a class file, the order of functions and var definitions is not an issue (aside from anonymous and nested functions which you should probably steer clear of anyway).

Let's start with line 82.  You call `bossGame()`, but when you look at the function, you've defined it so it requires a parameter:

```
function bossGame (event:KeyboardEvent)
```

It's expecting you to pass a `KeyboardEvent` to the function.  Though I'm not sure why because looking at that function it seems to have nothing to do with Keyboard input nor does it use that event in any way.

So, take out the parameter:

```
function bossGame()
```

Or, make it optional by giving it a default value:

```
function bossGame(event:KeyboardEvent = null)
```

---

For the second error.  Your `goGame` function is actually nested inside another function  `collision()` , so it has no scope except inside the collision function.  If you want to be able to access it outside of that function, then you should break it out.

As an aside, you comments beside your closing function brackets are often incorrect making it difficult to read your code.